Where can I find a non-local dictionary in Python?
I try to understand the namespaces according to LEGB:
I can find the Locals and Globals dictionary with the functions locals() and globals(), and the Built-ins with dir(builtins).
Where can I find the Enclosing namespace?
For example:
a = 1

def foo():
    b = 2
    def closure():
        c = 3
        print(globals())
        print(locals())
    return closure


foo()()

While the first print includes the a, and the second includes c, where is the b?
